# ext4 commit= mount option and dirty_writeback_centisecs

Tags: performance, io, linux-kernel, disk, ext4

I'm tring to understand the way bytes go from write() to the phisical disk plate to tune my picture server performance.

Thing I don't understand is what is the difference between these two: **commit=** mount option and **dirty_writeback_centisecs**. Looks like they are about the same procces of writing changes to the storage device, but still different.

I do not get it clear which one fires first on the way to the disk for my bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I just ran into this investigating mount options for an SDCard Ubuntu install on an ARM Chromebook.  Here's what I can tell you... 
Here's how to see the dirty and writeback amounts:

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep "Dirty" -A1
Dirty:             14232 kB
Writeback:          4608 kB
```

(edit: This dirty and writeback is rather high, I had a compile running when I ran this.)

So data to be written out is dirty.  Dirty data can still be eliminated (if say, a temporary file is created, used, and deleted before it goes to writeback, it'll never have to be written out).  As dirty data is moved into writeback, the kernel tries to combine smaller requests that may be into dirty into single larger I/O requests, this is one reason why dirty_expire_centisecs is usually not set too low.  Dirty data is usually put into writeback when a) Enough data is cached to get up to vm.dirty_background_ratio.  b) As data gets to be vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs centiseconds old (3000 default is 30 seconds) it is put into writeback.  vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs, a writeback daemon is run by default every 500 centiseconds (5 seconds) to actually flush out anything in writeback.

fsync will flush out an individual file (force it from dirty into writeback and wait until it's flushed out of writeback), and sync does that with everything.  As far as I know, it does this ASAP, bypassing any attempt to try to balance disk reads and writes, it stalls the device doing 100% writes until the sync completes.

commit=5 default ext4 mount option actually forces a sync() every 5 seconds on that filesystem.  This is intended to ensure that writes are not unduly delayed if there's heavy read activity (ideally losing a maximum of 5 seconds of data if power is cut or whatever.)    What I found with an Ubuntu install on SDCard (in a Chromebook) is that this actually just leads to massive filesystem stalls like every 5 seconds if you're writing much to the card, ChromeOS uses commit=600 and I applied that Ubuntu-side to good effect.

Comment: Is there a typo in your answer? When you say that data is put into write back, in case b), shoulnd't it be because it reaches ''vm.dirty_expire_centisecs'' instead of ''vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs''? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The dirty_writeback_centisecs, configures the daemons of the kernel Linux related to the virtual memory (that's why the vm). Which are in charge of making a write back from the RAM memory to all the storage devices, so if you configure the dirty_writeback_centisecs and you have 25 different storage devices mounted on your system it will have the same amount of time of writeback for all the 25 storage systems.
While the commit is done per storage device (actually is per filesystem) and is related to the sync process instead of the daemons from the virtual memory.
So you can see it as:

dirty_writeback_centisecs
writing from RAM to all filesystems

commit
each filesystem fetches from RAM